# Copy a project from Windows to Ubuntu in a way that git is recognized

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

I have copied a project (which was initialized with `git` and so contains a .git folder) from `Windows` to `Ubuntu`. If I now open the project on Ubuntu, VSCode tells me:

> The folder currently open doesn't have a git repository

If I run `git status`, I get the following output:

> fatal: cannot chdir to 'C:/Users/.../my_project': No such file or
> directory

What is the right way to copy the project with a relative path, so that it can be recognized by other systems?

Comment: There are some encoding issues while copying it from Windows to Ubuntu or vice versa. I usually upload it to hub and clone again. I don't face this issue by doing that.

Comment: But I have a lot of uncommited changes, which have to stay local for right now and which I also need on the other machine, so I can't just push everything to remote master.

Comment: You can create a branch which you can merge later if you want to.

Comment: But I also have other project, which don't have a remote master yet. Is there a way without uploading everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to package **files** and their **history** in a new local `.git` file:

```
git bundle create MyProject.git HEAD
```

Then you can copy/send the file from a Windows machine to Linux machine and clone it over there:

```
git clone MyProject.git /path/to/clone
```

And then e.g. add the origin remote:

```
git remote add origin https://dev.azure.com/path/to/_git/projectname
```